# MongoDB "too many files open" even after setting limits

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

When MongoDB starts up, I am greeted with a "too many files" error, even after editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` and setting the limit to `unlimited`.

```
Mar 09 18:29:13 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:13.199+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
Mar 09 18:29:13 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:13.199+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
Mar 09 18:29:13 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:13.199+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 29000 }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/home/databases/mongo" }, systemLog: { quiet: true } }
Mar 09 18:29:13 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:13.235+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /home/databases/mongo created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
Mar 09 18:29:13 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:13.236+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=37G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
Mar 09 18:29:15 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:15.676+0100 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (24) [1489080555:676881][1298:0x70e199ff3c80], file:collection-160--541918095290639536.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /home/databases/mongo/collection-160--541918095290639536.wt: handle-open: open: Too many open files
Mar 09 18:29:15 ns524052 mongod[1298]: 2017-03-09T18:29:15.676+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: 24: Too many open files at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 79
```

My `limits.conf` contains this

```
*                soft    nofile          unlimited
*                hard    nofile          unlimited
*                soft    nproc           unlimited
*                hard    nproc           unlimited
```

I've also tried using `ulimit` with no luck. Not sure what's happened. Running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: is running as root?

Comment: @FedericoSierra it runs as it's own mongodb user

Comment: Can you please provide output of `ulimit -a` as the user that runs MongoDB?

Comment: BTW no matter how the limits are propagated to your process, you can review the currently applicable limits for a process in the `/proc/<pid>/limits` "text" file. (With the numerical pid of the process)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 16.04 uses `systemd`, you have to adapt the `ulimit` settings on a per service basis. To do so, create a file `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.d/override.conf` and override the defaults.

```
root@xenial:~# sudo systemctl edit mongodb.service
```

Paste them:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
```

Ctrl + O then Ctrl + X to exit and file /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.d/override.conf is created

```
root@xenial:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
```

To check if these settings were applied, you can use `systemctl show`. First, let's see the values that are active.

```
root@xenial:~# systemctl --no-pager show mongodb.service | egrep 'NOFILE|NPROC'
LimitNOFILE=1024
LimitNOFILESoft=1024
LimitNPROC=7839
LimitNPROCSoft=7839
```

Then apply the settings.

```
root@xenial:~# systemctl daemon-reload 
root@xenial:~# systemctl --no-pager show mongodb.service | egrep 'NOFILE|NPROC'
LimitNOFILE=18446744073709551615
LimitNOFILESoft=18446744073709551615
LimitNPROC=18446744073709551615
LimitNPROCSoft=18446744073709551615
```

Comment: This caused mongo to completely fail for me with the error: `Failed to restart mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.` Only removing that junk service file and then re-running daemon-reload fixed it.

Comment: Then there seems something wrong with the service file. It might be better to open another question and put all the information including your service file in there.

Comment: `cat: /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service: No such file or directory` Did you test this on Ubuntu 16? The mongo-org package does not create any such file.

Comment: You can't just create that file anew. You have to copy and alter the original. _cp /lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service /etc/systemd/system/_ and then you can edit the new file _vim /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service_ and add those 2 new lines under the [Service] section. Then just stop & start mongodb.

Comment: @natli: you are right, that should go into the `override.conf` file. Updated answer and wondering how this could be accepted and upvoted. =0)

Comment: Thomas' solution worked for me, though the service file is `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` on Ubuntu 16.04 for MongoDB 3.6.6.
So the service override command changes to: sudo systemctl edit mongod.service

Answer (score 0):

Apart from user limits there might be opened files limit (max opened file descriptors limit to be precise) set in kernel:

```
# sysctl -a |grep -i fs.file-max
```

adjust it with

```
# sysctl -w fs.file-max=<opened_file_new_limit>
```

To keep kernel setting survive reboots - add file to /etc/sysctl.d directory, file should have .conf extension and content should be as following:

```
fs.file-max=<opened_file_new_limit>
```

Also check if there are no other files in /etc/sysctl.d directory that could overwrite these settings - there's another file when this can be set: /etc/sysctl.conf (if files from /etc/systcl.d are not read then use /etc/sysctl.conf)

That resolved issue for me.

sysctl config documentation: 
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html